# How to navigate outside the tabs with react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

I want to navigate to another screen from inside tab screen.

My problem is that I can't navigate outside the tab.

When I press on the flower image to navigate to my login screen the login screen opens inside the current tab!

[image: flower image]

[image: login page]

This is my stack navigator. The project contains the tab navigation

```
import { createAppContainer, createStackNavigator, createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({

    Login: Login,
    Developer: Developer,
    Projects: Projects,

},

    {
        headerMode: 'none',
        navigationOptions: {
            headerVisible: false,
        }
    });
```

This is my tab navigator screen:

```
const TabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({



    Photo: {
        screen: check_note_type2,

        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: (<Image
                style={{resizeMode:'contain', width: wp('4%'), height: hp('5%'), tintColor: '#bfb288' }}
                source={require('../assets/photo.png')} />)
        }
    },

    Voice: {
        screen: check_note_type3,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: (<Image
                style={{ resizeMode:'contain',width: wp('4%'), height: hp('5%'), tintColor: '#bfb288' }}
                source={require('../assets/voice.png')} />)
        }
    },


    Text: {
        screen: check_note_type4,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: (<Image
                style={{ resizeMode:'contain',width: hp('4%'), height: hp('5%'), tintColor: '#bfb288' }}
                source={require('../assets/note.png')} />)
        }
    },
```

Comment: Are you using react-navigation? How did you setup your tabs and login screen?

Comment: yes i use react-navigation my stack contain the tab and login screen

Comment: You should move your login screen into it's own stack.

Answer (score -3):

In this case, you can use navigation props outside a component with the API that react-navigation provides:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html